# $_GET in ASP and choose file

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to write ASP for the first time, I've only been using PHP for some years and never really got in to ASP. What I want to do is to get a value from the URLs get. For instance the url is like: page.asp?id=1

Then I want this value to be in an include like:

```
<!--#include file="somepage_$_GET[id].html"-->
```

How can this be achieved through ASP?

Peace

Comment: Are you using ASP or ASP.NET? It looks like ASP, so I have to ask: What reason do you have to learn a (highly) deprecated and unsupported framework?

Comment: Its for a client. So not really something im interested to learn. However i solved it. How should i write the solution?

Comment: Ok, great! Just type in your answer below and click "Post Your Answer". Then you can mark it as your answer after a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equialent term for `$_GET['id']` in PHP is in ASP `Request.QueryString("id")` if you per say are using `id` as your term.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Request.QueryString["id"]`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id;
    bool res = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id);
    if (res)
    {
        // id is present
    }
    else
    {
        // id is absent
    }

    ....
```